# How do I get rid of WARN Pet.species can be multi-cardinal?

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

In my result-view, in this if clause, I get the warning "WARN pet.species can be multi-cardinal". What does this mean and how do I get rid of it?

```
result-view {
  match: Pet (pet)

  render{
    layout{
      section{
        content{
          hbox{
            content{
              vbox{
                content{
                  text{
                    value ("#{upper(pet.name)}")
                    style (Title_S)
                  }
                }
              }
              if (pet.species == 'dog'){
                vbox{
                  content{
                    single-line{
                      image{
                        shape (Circle)
                        style (Title_S)
                        url ("/icons/dog-icon.png")                      
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }               
              } else-if (pet.species == 'cat') {
                vbox{
                  content{
                    single-line{
                      image{
                        shape (Circle)
                        style (Title_S)
                        url ("/icons/cat-icon.png")                      
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }   
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is the syntax wrong or something? The code still works but it'd be nice to get rid of the warnings.

Answer (score 1):

In concept model, set it as `Max(One)`.

Or put the render block in a if statement using size-of.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the problem for me.